# enabling captions on chromecast from android 4.2

Tags: android, chromecast, android-4.2-jelly-bean, google-cast

I use the Cast Companion Library in my android application. Captions work prefectly from Android 4.4+, when enabled by settings->accessibilty->captions. 
How do i make sure captions work on Android Jelly bean (4.1,4.2,4.3) too, as the option is not available in settings

Answer (score 0):

CCL's documentation has a section on how to enable the full support for Closed Captions (which includes a settings UI for changing the style) for all versions back to Ginger Bread, please refer to the documentation for details. The brief answer is that you would need to enable that feature when you initialize CCL and add a snippet to your existing settings page to provide an entry point to the Tracks setting page that CCL provides. You can look at the [CastVideos-android](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android) reference app as an example.